# Creation of multiple text files using C# in Visual Studio from DGView data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, text-files, createfile

Hi all I am having the following results in my data grid view, I want to print these data to multiple text files.

Text files should be in the format that it should start with `1stLine`(Column Value Please see the image) and end at `LastLine`(Column Value Please see the image).

consider filename1 column value as the filename of that file.

likewise, I want to create multiples files. I am not sure to create multiple files based on the range.

[image: Please find the table format here]

```
            private void Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int FileStart = 0;
        int FileEnd = 0;
        string FileName = "";
        String MyDir = "C:\\Test\\";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int rowcount = DGV.Rows.Count;
        int columncount = DGV.Columns.Count;
        for (int fn = 0; fn < rowcount - 1; fn++)// fro running down all rows
        {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DGV.Rows[fn].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) == false) //checking for the filename                  
               {
                    FileName = DGV.Rows[fn].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    builder.Clear();

                    FileStart = fn;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DGV.Rows[fn].Cells[4].Value.ToString()) == false) // this is where i tried to check the last line
                {
                    for (int row = fn; row < rowcount - 1; row++)
                    {
                        FileEnd = row;                                             
                    }
                }

                    for (int i = FileStart; i < rowcount - 1; i++) // here start generating the file based on first and last line .. but as of now i took rowcount as last line.. if i put last line returns nothing...i know this is where i am wrong, but i tried lot of options 
                    {
                        List<string> cols = new List<string>();
                        for (int j = 1; j < columncount; j++)
                        {
                            cols.Add(DGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
                        }

                        builder.AppendLine(string.Join("\n", cols.ToArray()));

                        if (!Directory.Exists(MyDir))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(MyDir);
                        }
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(MyDir + FileName, builder.ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(@"Text file was created.");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    fn = fn + 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Need output file like

Filename1

1stLine Bodytext1   BodyText2
Bodytext1   BodyText2
BodyText2   LastLine

Filename2

1stLine Bodytext1   BodyText2
Bodytext1   BodyText2
Bodytext1   BodyText2
Bodytext1   BodyText2
Bodytext1   BodyText2   LastLine

Filename3

1stLine Bodytext1   BodyText2
Bodytext1   BodyText2
Bodytext1   BodyText2
Bodytext1   BodyText2   LastLine

Comment: "Text files should be in the format that it should start with the first line and end at last line." that's a weird format.. never saw such a file ;P

Comment: @mong zhu Please see the image first line and last line means the column value of the data grid view

Comment: ok, do you know how to extract the values from the `DataGridView` ? do you know how to write a file?

Comment: I understood this point :) that was me trying to be funny ;) I guess I failed that one

Comment: @Mong zhu since I am beginner , I read about stream writer function , I can create a single file

Comment: You would write one file after the other. Unless you have not time, then you can parallerlize it, but may be we should not start with that. Can you please post the code where you try to extract the values from the `DataGridView` ? and the code that you wrote to write the file?

Comment: I am currently using like this
            StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(MyDir+FileName);

            string lines = "";
            

            for (int row = 0; row < Viewer.RowCount; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < Viewer.ColumnCount; col++)
                {

                    lines = Viewer.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString();

                }

                sW.WriteLine(lines);
            }

            sW.Close();
        }

Comment: @SivaVikas part of learning is `Doing` and in order for anyone to help you , you need to help yourself first, do some research, learn to code by googling for examples don't expect others to do the code for you. `This is not a Code it for me Site`

Comment: please post the additional information as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47807861/edit) into your post. You can format the code and it becomes readable. In comments it is a paint to read code. Thank you

Comment: @MethodMan I am doing , I have done lot to get me at this much. I searched lot . I just need help as i don't have much time , otherwise i can do with my own but it will take time. I will learn from this code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to write the algorithm down in words. Imagine you would need to do it by hand. How would the recipe of actions look like? Here is one example:

1) you start walking down all rows that you have. (for-all rows)

2) `IF` you encounter a non-empty item in column `1`, you know that this is your starting point and you remember that value.

3) now you know that at the very same row there is the `1stLine` value in column with the index `1`. You take and remember that value as well.

4) now at this point you can start with your `BodyText` collection of values.
start at the same row that you are and walk down the rows. In each row you take the value from column `2` and `3` then you check in column `4`. `IF` it is empty you put a `\n` and the end of your line and continue with the next row doing the step 4 again. `ELSE` it means that you have reached the `LastLine` and you can now write the content that you have remembered into a file.

5) Now you would clear the memory of the last file, take the next row and continue with step **2**

Hope that helps you to solve your problem. IF you have questions, just ask in a comment. Good Luck

EDIT:

Ok with you code at hand let's see:

1) It is useless to check for the last line before you start the second loop. If you look at step 4) of my algorithm you need to gather first the values from column 3 and 4 and AFTER that you check for the column 4!

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DGV.Rows[fn].Cells[4].Value.ToString()) == false)
    break; // This will cancel the inner loop and you return to the outer loop
```

Comment: Thanks Mong zhu, I ll try from your guidelines

Comment: @SivaVikas you're welcome, just drop a comment if you get stuck

Comment: GridView1.Columns[Index].HeaderText; no prob got the syntax..:)

Comment: You there i got stuck in the end

Comment: so i have done that.. its creating multiple files... but i am unable to take last line condition into loop. last line will be always last row . i don`t know how make it....trying so far ... shal i post the code so far i hav done

Comment: @bowbow jo, edit and post the code, then we can have a look on it :)

Comment: Have a look and give some suggestion

Comment: @bowbow can you try to mark the steps from my algorithm with comments in your code 1) 2) and so on ?=! That would be helpful

Comment: Please check whether it is  ok for you

Comment: Thanks for your support mong.. i have done.. :) broke the loop in the correct place.

Comment: is it possible to accept both as anser .. because both answers helped already tried to mark but didn`t work.

Comment: @bowbow no that does not work, you have to choose. But you can upvote the other answer. As soon as you have enough reputation your vote will be counted and he/she will get the deserved reputation :)

Comment: Okay.. i don't enough reputation to do..i am having one more doubt.. could you help me out on this

Comment: @bowbow Hi, what is bothering you ?=! :)

Comment: hi.. i have created application to generate multiple files from sql table .. after creation of those files... same sql table to be deleted.. i have checked..but no idea so far... give me some suggestion... to tackle it....

Comment: @bowbow what exactly is the problem? you don't know how to delete the table?

Comment: I know to delete the table.... actually its not a problem..... what I am doing for file generation ...1. I am creating a dummy SQL table.. 2. I am fetching same data to datagridview. 3. From DGView i generating files.... 4. After completion of the generation of files.... want to delete the same table.....(This feature i am going to add). have you got my point?

Comment: "I know to delete the table" if you know, where is the problem? Make a button and delete the table. ?=! confused

Comment: its not a manual deletion... deletion need to be done automatically after the completion of files..ok leave it off ...no prob...

Comment: @bowbow after you have created all the files, and you are sure that the data is save, just drop the table in the code. At the end of the code which creates the files. May be make an own method to do that

Answer (score 0):

Below code breaks the DataGrid.DataSource Datatable into chunks that will go into each file.

```
private void SaveToFiles(DataTable srcData)
        {
            if (srcData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                int FileStart = 0;
                int FileEnd = -1;

                while (FileStart < srcData.Rows.Count)
                {
                    for (int row = FileStart; row < srcData.Rows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(srcData.Rows[row].Field<string>(0)) == false)
                        {
                            FileStart = row;
                        }
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(srcData.Rows[row].Field<string>(4)) == false)
                        {
                            FileEnd = row;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    var data = srcData.AsEnumerable().Skip(FileStart).Take(FileEnd - FileStart + 1);
                    SaveFile(data.ToList());
                    FileStart = FileEnd + 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

You need to add code to write the text to file in the format you wish - in place of the comment.

```
private void SaveFile(List<DataRow> fileData)
        {
            if (fileData != null && fileData.Count > 0)
            {
                string fileName = fileData[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();

                using (var fileStrm = File.Create(fileName + ".txt"))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter wrtr = new StreamWriter(fileStrm))
                    {
                       // handle writing to file here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: not only for checking it should include first and last line

Comment: Something Like this
File: filename1.txt
First Line
BodyText1 Bodytext2

BodyText1 Bodytext2

BodyText1 Bodytext2

BodyText1 Bodytext2

BodyText1 Bodytext2
Last Line
.. until you reach Last Line

Comment: @SivaVikas - from your question - it isnt very clear what is it that you exactly want. we understand the grid data that you have. Please also show sample of the file that you want. i can then guide you.

Comment: I need something like this                                                                                                    
1stLine Bodytext1 BodyText2 
Bodytext1 BodyText2 
BodyText2 LastLine
1stLine Bodytext1 BodyText2 
Bodytext1 BodyText2 
Bodytext1 BodyText2 
Bodytext1 BodyText2 
Bodytext1 BodyText2 LastLine
1stLine Bodytext1 BodyText2 
Bodytext1 BodyText2 
Bodytext1 BodyText2 
Bodytext1 BodyText2 LastLine

Comment: @SivaVikas - Thats better. i will post the code answer soon.

Comment: l`ll Check and let you know . Extremely thanks for you ease response....